# gazebo on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys :)
can i install GAZEBO on UBUNTU 11.10 form gazebosim.org? which version? tnx :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56990/gazebo-on-ubuntu-11.10?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1628/gazebo-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric/

---

Originally posted by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) with karma: 139 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gazebo developers have requested that questions like this be directed to http://answers.gazebosim.org.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2